# Help identifying a diode

Tags: diodes, identification

I am looking for some help identifying some diodes in the photos in the link below. They are being used in a hacked emergency call system. 
One of the diodes has some of the following nomenclature. ECG125S 8315
This circuitry has 2 28 volt 4.76 watt bulbs being lit and a 24 v relay be picked.
any help would be appreciated.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/do6cb0153ocroch/AAC6t6nGDvoFcrvxJHV-6VUQa?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a general rectifier diode. You may be able to replace it with a 1N4007.

http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/198507.pdf?_ga=2.51662249.1468387824.1547322965-1212020419.1541496125

https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds28002.pdf

However, if your bulb is drawing 2A continuously (4.76W/2.28V=2.08A), a bigger diode like 1N5408 may be better. https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds28007.pdf

ECG125 also may refer to the 2.5A version
https://www.datasheets360.com/part/detail/ecg125/-2631702309373168251/
and http://talonelectronics.com/shop/item.aspx?itemid=30 . Either way, depending on current one of the commonly available 1N4007 or 1N5408 will be fine. If max voltage in system is guaranteed to not exceed 24V, you can even use the lower voltage versions (1N4001, 1N5400 etc). However, the lower voltage versions cost the same (or sometimes more) as the higher voltage versions.

PS: I think I may have misread. Did you mean TWO 28V 4.76W bulbs? If so, the current is 0.17A at 28V. So 1N4007 is just fine (for up to 5 bulbs in parallel).